# Magento 2: How to override table rate model

Tags: magento2

I am getting an issue while overriding the table rate model.

```
namespace Abc\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;


class Tablerate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate
{

    protected $_code = 'tablerate';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultConditionName = 'package_weight';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_conditionNames = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_resultMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\ResourceModel\Carrier\TablerateFactory
     */
    protected $_tablerateFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $resultMethodFactory
     * @param \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\ResourceModel\Carrier\TablerateFactory $tablerateFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $resultMethodFactory,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\ResourceModel\Carrier\TablerateFactory $tablerateFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_resultMethodFactory = $resultMethodFactory;
        $this->_tablerateFactory = $tablerateFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
        foreach ($this->getCode('condition_name') as $k => $v) {
            $this->_conditionNames[] = $k;
        }
    }



    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
            }
        }

        // Free shipping by qty
        $freeQty = 0;
        $freePackageValue = 0;

        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                            $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping() || $item->getAddress()->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeShipping = $item->getFreeShipping() ?
                        $item->getFreeShipping() : $item->getAddress()->getFreeShipping();
                    $freeShipping = is_numeric($freeShipping) ? $freeShipping : 0;
                    $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                    $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
                }
            }
            $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
            $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
        }

        if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
            $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
            $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_defaultConditionName);
        }

        // Package weight and qty free shipping
        $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
        $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

        $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);

        $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            if ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {
                $shippingPrice = 0;
            } else {
                $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
            }
            $method = $this->createShippingMethod($shippingPrice, $rate['cost']);
            $result->append($method);
        } elseif ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {

            /**
             * Promotion rule was applied for the whole cart.
             *  In this case all other shipping methods could be omitted
             * Table rate shipping method with 0$ price must be shown if grand total is more than minimal value.
             * Free package weight has been already taken into account.
             */
            $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
            $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
            $rate = $this->getRate($request);
            if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
                $method = $this->createShippingMethod(0, 0);
                $result->append($method);
            }
        } else {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error $error */
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                        'carrier' => $this->_code,
                        'carrier_title' => $this->getConfigData('title'),
                        'error_message' => $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'),
                    ],
                ]
            );
            $result->append($error);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get rate.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function getRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->_tablerateFactory->create()->getRate($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get code.
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $code
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getCode($type, $code = '')
    {
        $codes = [
            'condition_name' => [
                'package_weight' => __('Weight vs. Destination'),
                'package_value_with_discount' => __('Price vs. Destination'),
                'package_qty' => __('# of Items vs. Destination'),
            ],
            'condition_name_short' => [
                'package_weight' => __('Weight (and above)'),
                'package_value_with_discount' => __('Order Subtotal (and above)'),
                'package_qty' => __('# of Items (and above)'),
            ],
        ];

        if (!isset($codes[$type])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The "%1" code type for Table Rate is incorrect. Verify the type and try again.', $type)
            );
        }

        if ('' === $code) {
            return $codes[$type];
        }

        if (!isset($codes[$type][$code])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The "%1: %2" code type for Table Rate is incorrect. Verify the type and try again.', $type, $code)
            );
        }

        return $codes[$type][$code];
    }

    /**
     * Get allowed shipping methods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['bestway' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * Get the method object based on the shipping price and cost
     *
     * @param float $shippingPrice
     * @param float $cost
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method
     */
    private function createShippingMethod($shippingPrice, $cost)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_resultMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('bestway');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($cost);
        return $method;
    }
}
```

Issue is:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Config\Source\Tablerate
```

Please suggest

Comment: why are you not calling the parent constructor?

Comment: Please suggest me the code where i'm wrong

Comment: why you donot use Plugin

Comment: I have not used the plugin

Comment: Checked this link for plugin

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195285/magento-2-override-tablerate-model


How to call in di.xml file